# How Can I change Character controller rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate the character controller it-self. Is this possible because i tried to rotate the cylinder which has character controller component.
    But the problem is as depicted in picture mesh is rotating and character controller itself not rotating. I googled and found transform rotation option
     but not any option available not rotate character controller it-self. Actually I have camera transform whom i want to rotate but the problem is camera rotating character controller not.
[image]

Comment: you should need to read my question twice

Comment: Hmm, is `character controller` a script? Or is it a `GameObject`

Comment: Character controller is unity own component

Comment: Yea I was guessing that you were referring to that `CharacterController`.. But in that case what do u mean by "rotating a character controller"? Do you mean to rotate the character controller's `collider`?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think you can "rotate" the capsule collider of the `CharacterController`. Its always fixed upright.. you can adjust it's height, radius and center, but not it's rotation. Well, you have to use an upright model if you want to use the `CharacterController`. Either that or you have to fatten / shrink the `CharacterController` collider.

Comment: I find it a bit unclear what you're trying to do and you're missing ou timportant info, can you
1-Show us the code you're using
2-Show us the object hierarchy in the editor
3-Explain why you are trying to rotate it yourself ?